# How to define IDLE calltip for custom exception in python

Tags: python, class, exception, python-idle

I am working on exceptions, and I will like my exception to have a message like in definitions and other exceptions:
[image: ValueError description]
However, when I define my own exception:
[image: My own error description]
How can I change that message?

**NOTE:** Is this possible just with python?

Comment: Check here: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/exceptions.c#L432 , this is coming from c implementation

Comment: @IronFist, ok... I've no idea how to use c so I guess I will just have to leave it as it is.

Comment: Below answer should be enough for your needs

Comment: @Rob I can't copy and paste a pop-up window!

Comment: Then type it in as the rule states.

Comment: @ Rob  By rule, you are right and I have made similar comments.  But this seems like an appropriate exception.  It would be difficult to properly 'type' IDLE's yellow background calltip popup to make it so instantly clear to an experienced IDLE user what he was asking.  The text and original title were not so clear because Leo did not know the term 'calltip'.

Comment: The supposed duplicate is not a duplicate as it does not answer the question and the notice would best be removed.  Jaime's answer is an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this:

```
class NumberError(Exception):
    """The custom message"""
    pass
```

This is called a docstring and, as it's name suggests, it's used to add documentation about the class, function, etc.

Now you can also do:

```
help(NumberError)
```

And it will print the docstring

More info [here](https://realpython.com/documenting-python-code/)

Comment: I would say he is referring to the message that appears when hovering the mouse over the class name like in the photos he added.

Comment: Can confirm that the docstring is used by IDLE for the hint message.

Comment: @JaimeEtxebarria, yep, that's correct

Comment: @JaimeEtxebarria Your answer is correct as far as it goes.  To continue, the IDLE calltip appears when one types the open paren '(' and disappears when one types close paren ')' or moves the cursor out of the argument area.  One can also get it by selecting menu item Edit => Show calltip or with the hotkey displayed on the menu item.

Comment: @IronFist See comment above about calltip display.